# semantic-release not creating new release and changelog not pushed to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, semantic-release

I have the following problem: As soon, as my pipeline starts and a release should be published by semantic-release, nothing happens. Only the correct label is created.

My `.releaserc` looks like this:

```json
{
  "branches": ["master"],
  "plugins": [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    [
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      {
        "changelogFile": "docs/CHANGELOG.md"
      }
    ],
    [
      "@semantic-release/gitlab",
      {
        "assets": [{"path": "docs/CHANGELOG.md"}]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The stage in my `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
release:
  image: node:13
  stage: release
  only:
    refs:
    - master
  before_script:
    - 'echo Stage - Release started'
  script:
    - npm install @semantic-release/gitlab
    - npm install @semantic-release/changelog
    - npx semantic-release
  after_script:
    - 'echo Stage - Release finished'
```

As I said, everything works as intended. The pipeline succeeds and there are no warnings within the logs. Anyways, the only thing that happens is, that the label is created correctly. I do not have a new release. And I do not have the new `CHANGELOG.md`. Did I maybe miss something within my pipeline or the config?

```
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.4.4
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:03 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[12:01:05 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Run automated release from branch master on repository https://gitlab-ci-token:[secure]@gitlab.***.com/***.git
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Allowed to push to the Git repository
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/gitlab] › ℹ  Verify GitLab authentication (https://gitlab.***.com/api/v4)
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "verifyConditions" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found git tag v1.1.0 associated with version 1.1.0 on branch master
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Found 3 commits since last release
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: Merge branch '***' into 'master'
Resolve "***"
Closes #5
See merge request ***!3
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: ***
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The commit should not trigger a release
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analyzing commit: feat: ***
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  The release type for the commit is minor
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/commit-analyzer] › ℹ  Analysis of 3 commits complete: minor release
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "analyzeCommits" of plugin "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  The next release version is 1.2.0
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "generateNotes" of plugin "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "generateNotes" of plugin "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "prepare" of plugin "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/changelog] › ℹ  Create /builds/***/docs/CHANGELOG.md
[12:01:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Completed step "prepare" of plugin "@semantic-release/changelog"
[12:01:08 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Created tag v1.2.0
[12:01:08 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "publish" of plugin "@semantic-release/gitlab"
```

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you find the root cause?

Comment: @JasimKhanAfridi sadly no

Answer (score 1):

The default plugins that 'semantic-release' uses are:

```json
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
    "@semantic-release/npm"
    "@semantic-release/github"
```

For your particular configuration, which matches mine, you have to replace the `github` one with the `gitlab` one.

In my particular case, based on the example in the [documentation](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/plugins.md#plugin-options-configuration), and the tests I've done, I needed to specify the `@semantic-release/git` plugin as well, since it seems to be the one in charge of creating the release.

So, the full configuration you should use is:

```json
    {
      "branches": ["master"],
      "plugins": [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
        [
          "@semantic-release/changelog",
          {
            "changelogFile": "docs/CHANGELOG.md"
          }
        ],
        [
          "@semantic-release/gitlab",
          {
            "assets": [{"path": "docs/CHANGELOG.md"}]
          }
        ],
        "@semantic-release/git"
      ]
    }
```

Regards!

Comment: Adding the git plugin to the end solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, but not with the file `.releaserc`. I was using a `release` key in the `package.json` file.

In my case the file `CHANGELOG.md` was not being created because I added the `plugins` list at the root level of the json file. But it should be inside the `release` object. When I fixed that the changelog file got created.

This is the correct json:

```json
{
  "name": "some-name",
  "description": "some description",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^6.0.2",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
    "semantic-release": "^20.1.0"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0-development",
  "scripts": {
    "semantic-release": "semantic-release"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/some-user/some-repo.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted"
  },
  "release": {
    "branches": [
      "main"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      "@semantic-release/changelog",
      "@semantic-release/git",
      "@semantic-release/github"
    ]
  }
}
```